# Java += meaning

Tags: java, operators

I have seen this symbol/operator in a block of code:

```
a+=1;
```

But I cannot figure out what it does. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

The last phrase is important if the left-hand side has side effects:

```
array[i++] += 1;
```

This is *not* equivalent to:

```
array[i++] = array[i++] + 1;
```

The first expression will increment `i` once. The second will increment `i` twice and will assign the right-hand value to a different element of `array` than will the first expression.

I should note that these kind of side-effect statements are not good programming form, despite the fact that you often find them used.

The cast is also important because the type of `(E1) op (E2)` may not be assignment-compatible with `E1`. For example, if `a` is of type `short`, then `a++` is not equivalent to `a = a + 1`. The latter will not compile because the type of `a + 1` is `int` and cannot be assigned to a `short` variable without a cast. That's why the spec in this case says that `a++` is equivalent to `a = (short) ((a) + (1))`. The same thing goes if `a` is of type `char` or `byte`.

Comment: +1. I didn't think of this. Edited my answer to reflect this point.

Answer (score 10):

It is equivalent to

```
a = a + 1;
```

Comment: Not quite equivalent. For instance, if `a` is a `byte` or `short`, then `a += 1` is legal, but `a = a + 1` does not work. The problem is that `a + 1` is an `int`, so it has to be narrowed by a cast before it can be assigned to `a` again.

Comment: Wow! I did not think about it! Great comment! :)

Answer (score 7):

```
x += y;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x + y;
```

There are similar operators for the other mathematical operations: -=, *=, /=. For example:

```
x *= y;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x * y;
```

(EDIT: The above assumes there are no 'side-effects' in x; ie, preincrement or postincrement operators. Edited to reflect Ted Hopp's point)

Answer (score 5):

It is shorthand for the following:

```
a = a + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It means `a = a + 1` i.e increment `a`.

Comment: That's not quite the case...it's more like adding one to `a` instead.